# How can I trim mp4 video by using ffmpeg only encoding connection point

Tags: ffmpeg

I trim a mp4 video by using ffmpeg like this.

```
$ ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:01:00 -c copy out.mp4
```

But I get a movie in which first 10 second video does not exist. (sound only)
I wanted to re-encode the movie by using HandBrake, but it is not recognized properly with following error message.

> Your Source may be copy protected, badly mastered or in a format which
>   HandBrake does not support.  Please refer to the Documentation and FAQ
>   (see Help Menu).

I think it happens because of base frame or something like that.

Is there options to make ffmepg re-encode the first 10 second video and concatenate with not re-rencoded remaining 50 second long video?

Comment: Not really feasible since the bitstreams would have to be exactly the same settings in order to be able to concatenate them. If the first 10 seconds do not exist, have you tried simply re-encoding (if that's what you wanted to do anyway?)

Comment: I don't understand why I can't use the same settings for the first 10 seconds bitstreams? Is it impossible to know the values of setting from the encoded video? Or can't use my last setting for the encoding?

Comment: Oh.. If you generated the `in.mp4` and know the exact settings, then you could try and re-encode the first ten seconds and concat them with the rest.

Comment: I said 10 seconds, but it is not exactly 10 seconds. The exact time depends on the base frame. How can I find the length of removed video correctly? And as far as I know, if I concatenate two mp4 videos, the first per seconds of the latter video have some jumbles, isn't it? I've tried with ffmpeg and MP4Box on several times, but the jumbles happens always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I get a movie in which first 10 second video does not exist. (sound only)

Concatenating might result in choppy video. I've personally been avoiding cutting with bitstream copies whenever I can. I don't think you'll be able to find out *exactly* where it will cut off, but it's definitely at some keyframe.

Basically if you use `-ss` after `-i`, ffmpeg will seek to the timestamp, regardless if it's a keyframe or not. It'll then write the output stream from there, but the player can only start from the next IDR picture*, so this is why you experience black video until the decoder can start displaying something.

You could try specifying `-ss` before `-i`, which will make ffmpeg seek to keyframes only, and thus produce an output bitstream that should display video right away.

<sub>* An IDR (instantaneous decoding refresh) picture in H.264 is a picture that consists only of intra-coded slices and does not require other pictures to be decoded. The decoder can only start decoding once it receives an IDR picture. Roughly speaking, you could call it a keyframe, although technically it's not the same.</sub>